# Does anybody know how to use the Approximate Nearest Neighbor Search provide by Spark MLlib?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, nearest-neighbor

I want to use the Approximate Nearest Neighbor Search provide by Spark MLlib [(ref.)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-features.html#approximate-nearest-neighbor-search) but I'm super lost because I didn't find an example or something to guide me. The only info provided for the previous link is:

> Approximate nearest neighbor search takes a dataset (of feature
>   vectors) and a key (a single feature vector), and it approximately
>   returns a specified number of rows in the dataset that are closest to
>   the vector.
>
> Approximate nearest neighbor search accepts both transformed and
>   untransformed datasets as input. If an untransformed dataset is used,
>   it will be transformed automatically. In this case, the hash signature
>   will be created as outputCol.
>
> A distance column will be added to the output dataset to show the true
>   distance between each output row and the searched key.
>
> Note: Approximate nearest neighbor search will return fewer than k
>   rows when there are not enough candidates in the hash bucket.

Does anybody know how to use the Approximate Nearest Neighbor Search provide by Spark MLlib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you can find an example https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#lsh-algorithms :

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSH
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

val dfA = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 1.0)),
  (1, Vectors.dense(1.0, -1.0)),
  (2, Vectors.dense(-1.0, -1.0)),
  (3, Vectors.dense(-1.0, 1.0))
)).toDF("id", "keys")

val dfB = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (4, Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0)),
  (5, Vectors.dense(-1.0, 0.0)),
  (6, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.0)),
  (7, Vectors.dense(0.0, -1.0))
)).toDF("id", "keys")

val key = Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0)

val brp = new BucketedRandomProjectionLSH()
  .setBucketLength(2.0)
  .setNumHashTables(3)
  .setInputCol("keys")
  .setOutputCol("values")

val model = brp.fit(dfA)

// Feature Transformation
model.transform(dfA).show()
// Cache the transformed columns
val transformedA = model.transform(dfA).cache()
val transformedB = model.transform(dfB).cache()

// Approximate similarity join
model.approxSimilarityJoin(dfA, dfB, 1.5).show()
model.approxSimilarityJoin(transformedA, transformedB, 1.5).show()
// Self Join
model.approxSimilarityJoin(dfA, dfA, 2.5).filter("datasetA.id < datasetB.id").show()

// Approximate nearest neighbor search
model.approxNearestNeighbors(dfA, key, 2).show()
model.approxNearestNeighbors(transformedA, key, 2).show()
```

The code above is from spark documentation.

Comment: So embarrassed! I didn't realize that code is for the nearest neighbor search! Thanks

Comment: No problem ! :)